# How do I use DrawPrimitiveUP so it uses the color value from my defined struct?

Tags: c++, directx

I need to draw lines using DrawPrimitiveUP and I need it to use the color value from my defined structure.

Important snippets from the code:

```
struct PointVertexColor
{
 float x, y, z;   // Position
 DWORD color;   //Colour
};

#define D3DFVF_PointVertexColor ( D3DFVF_XYZ | D3DFVF_DIFFUSE ) 

PointVertexColor myLines[1024];

device->DrawPrimitiveUP( D3DPT_LINELIST, myLinesCount, myLines, sizeof( PointVertexColor ) );
```

I have a pointlight set, lighting enabled and ambient lighting also.

Problem is that if I set up a material it uses the materials color and not the one from my data struct. How do I set it up so it uses the DWORD color and then set it back to use material for later code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was obvious if you know it - you can't use vertex color and lighting at the same time. The solution is to disable lighting for that part of the code and then re-enable it later.

Hope it helps someone with the same question.

Comment: Actually, you _can_ use vertex color and lighting. See render state D3DRS_DIFFUSEMATERIALSOURCE, e.g.

Comment: tried that but it seemed it had no effect (color/material), maybe I had something else wrong also there.